# How I can retreive rtp timestamp with ffmpeg C API without private headers?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, rtp

I use ffmpeg libraries in my app for rtp streaming. For my purpose I need some unique "id" for each frame that can be sended to client app. I want to use rtp timestamp of frame for this purpose. How I can get rtp timestamp from ffmpeg via public headers?

And second question: if no ways for get rtp, how I can inject some small my data to AVPacket on server side and extract it on client side?

Comment: You can use dts/pts, to use it as timestamp. But this you can get only after decoding those frames.

Comment: But dts/pts are different for one frame on server side and client side.

Comment: are you trans-coding/re-encoding frames at server side, before streaming?

Comment: My app grab frames from camera, encode with libx264 and send via rtp.